# UINavigationBar resizes and covers UIViews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

We instanitate a UINavigationController and a UIViewController from a storyboard like so:

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"AddOrder" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateInitialViewController];
UIViewController *topVC = ((UINavigationController *) vc).topViewController;

vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

[image]

From here, it looks like the `UIViewController` isn't taking up the whole `UIWindow`, it looks 20 pts down like on ios6. You can even see the underlying `UISplitViewController`'s divider at the top left if you look closely.

The issue is, when the user taps an option on the `UITableView` on the`UIViewController` we call `[self performSegueWithIdentifier: sender:]` which pushes a new `UIViewController` on, but when they   rotate it, it looks like so:

[image]

A little cramped, to say the least. **But now, when we go back to the first `UIViewController` and rotate, we get this**:

[image]

Issue is, the search bar is now covered. You'll notice you cannot see the underlying `UISplitViewController` anymore either. As you can see, it looks like now the `UINavigationBar` is covering up the other 20 pts and is larger in height.

I kind of "fixed" the issue by calling `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;` but that just shoves the `UIView` pretty far down. I also toyed with adding `[UIViewController attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation]` but nothing. In Apple's HIG it states that a navigation bar should not change it's height on the iPad, yet this is happening to me when I log out the frame.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is self here: [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL]; is it the splitviewcontroller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi You can create the view controller with these properties
[image]

And add the modal on the the application window

```
[self.view.window.rootViewController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I think your problem will be solved by this.

Answer (score 0):

Just fix it by

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

Put this line in `viewDidLoad` method and then create other controllers.

It's only working on iOS 7 and latter.

Comment: He can check whether `self` responds to automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets like so: `if([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setAutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets:)])` so it works on older iOS versions.